# Open editor and edit diff in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, emacs

I'm looking to write a python script which does the following:

- Takes in two file paths, `a` and `b`;
- Opens an editor to display and edit a diff of the files at `a` and `b` (for now assume that files exist at the paths); and
- Captures the output of the editor once the buffer is closed.

I'm aware of `difflib` and know basic file io. What I don't know is how to *send* the diff buffer to an editor and *capture* the modified buffer.

In this case I'd like to open an emacsclient buffer, but ideally the solution should rely on the `$EDITOR` of the user.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is a temporary file. Create one, open it with `$EDITOR`, then read it back when editor exits.

Comment: So create a temporary file, and call emacs client on the temporary file with subprocess? And then read the file when subprocess terminates?